# Preg_replace Regex That Ignores Enclosing Wordpress Shortcodes

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace, regex-lookarounds

I'm building a PHP function that replaces "My Term" (for this example) in a user generated string with preg_replace, except when "My Term" is situated within enclosing shortcode tags, like so:

```
'Replace My Term here [link attr="ignore My Term here"]ignore My Term here[/link]'
```

So in essence, the regex should replace all instances of "My Term" in a string, unless they are between "[link" and "[/link]".

I came up with the following regex, which matches "My Term" when it's not surrounded by alphanumerical characters and when it's not between square brackets.

```
preg_replace('~(?<![A-Za-z0-9\]])My Term(?![A-Za-z0-9\[])(?=(?:(?:[^\]]*+\]){2})*+[^\]]*+\z)~', $replacement, $text);
```

However! This also ignores all instances of "My Term" between random shortcodes, like so:

```
'[shortcode1] this instance of My Term is ignored when it shouldnt be [shortcode2]'
```

How can I alter this regex to only ignore text when it is placed between enclosing "[link" and "[/link]" tags?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, turns out I was using an entirely wrong approach by using lookarounds for single bracket characters.

My current regex

```
'~(?<![A-Za-z0-9\]"])My Term(?![A-Za-z0-9\["])(?!(.(?!\[link))*\[/link\])~'
```

does exactly what I needed: preg_replace now ignores "My Term" between [link] tags and when it's next to a quote, but not when it's between other random shortcodes.

Comment: Will not work if there is another tag before, like: `[tag]Replace [/tag]My Term here [link attr="ignore My Term here"]ignore My Term here[/link]`